# Add a div when click on a li or link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add a new div when click on a li or link

The problem is when I click on the first div it works. But I want to add a div when an immediate previous li is clicked. Suppose, when I click on "1" a new div "2" will create. Then if I click on "2" a new div "3" will open and so on.
After that, If I click on any previous div, all the divs will close except the next div and previous divs. Suppose, there are 1,2,3,4,5 div open. If I click on 2, only 1,2,3 div will visible. others will hide.

How can I do that?

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(e) {
  var isPresent = false;
  var whoIsIt = $(this).attr('data');
  $('#data .data').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).attr('data-conversation-between') == whoIsIt) {
      isPresent = true;
    }
  });
  if (!isPresent) {
    $('#data').append('<div class="data" data-conversation-between="' + whoIsIt + '"><ul><li class="title"><a  href="#"><img src="img/1.jpg" class="profile" alt=""><div class="details"> <p>Tusher</p><p>Designation</p></div></a> </li></ul> </div>');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().prepend($(this));
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}

.data {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 13%;
}

.data a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.data ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.profile {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 13px;
}

.details {
  font-size: 13px;
}

li.title {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.active {
  background: #ececec;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="data">
    <ul>
      <li class="title">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" class="profile" alt="">
          <div class="details">
            <p>Tusher</p>
            <p>Designation</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="data">

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delegate

```
$('.main').on('click','.title:last', function(e) {
```

and

```
$('#data').on('click', '.title', function(e) {
  const hasMore = $(this).closest(".data").next().length;
  if (hasMore>0) $(this).closest(".data").siblings().remove(); // this should have worked
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.main').on('click', '.title:last', function(e) {
    const $new = $(this).closest('.data').clone();
    $('.details p',$new).text('Tusher '+$('.main .data').length)
    $('.main').append($new)
    
  });

  $('.main').on('click', '.title', function(e) {
    const hasMore = $(this).closest('.data').nextAll().length
    if (hasMore > 1) {
      $(this).closest(".data").siblings().remove(); 
    }
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}

.data {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 13%;
}

.data a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.data ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.profile {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 13px;
}

.details {
  font-size: 13px;
}

li.title {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.active {
  background: #ececec;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="data">
    <ul>
      <li class="title">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" class="profile" alt="">
          <div class="details">
            <p>Tusher</p>
            <p>Designation</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! What about the removing part. After opening multiple div, if I click any of them, all the previous div and only the next div will visible, others will hide. If I click "2" no div. 1,2,3 no div will visible. Others will hide.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure why my remove code does not work. Perhaps you can ask another question?

Comment: Everything is perfect. Except for one problem. There will be multiple li inside the div. This will come dynamically. Every li should be workable. And if I click on the first div, it should only open the second div. Can you please help me more?

Comment: I have updated the script. It is easier now I do not have the data div

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my problem.

```js
            function childData(_id) {
             var tRow = $(".organogram li").length,
              row = parseInt(_id)+1;
             for (var i = row; i <= tRow; i++) {
                 $("#dept-"+i).remove();
             }
             var data =  "<li id='dept-"+row+"' class='team'>"
         
             +"<div class='data'><ul> "
             +"<li class='title' onclick='thisNode(this)'><a href='#'><img src='img/1.jpg' class='profile' ><div class='details'> <p>Tusher1</p><p>Designation</p></div></a> </li>"
             +"<li class='title' onclick='thisNode(this)'><a href='#'><img src='img/1.jpg' class='profile' ><div class='details'> <p>Tusher2</p><p>Designation</p></div></a> </li>"
             +"<li class='title' onclick='thisNode(this)'><a href='#'><img src='img/1.jpg' class='profile' ><div class='details'> <p>Tusher3</p><p>Designation</p></div></a> </li>"
             +"</ul> </div></li>";
             $(".organogram").append(data);
         }
         function thisNode(_this){
             var _id = $(_this).closest(".team").attr("id").match(/\d+/);
         
             $(_this).closest("ul").find("li").removeClass( "active" );
             $(_this).addClass( "active" );
         
         $(_this).closest("ul").prepend($(_this));
             childData(_id);
         }
```

```css
         ul{
        padding:0px;
         list-style-type: none;
         }
         .data {
         border: 1px solid;
         margin: 5px;
         float: left;
         width: 13%;
         }
         .data a{
         text-decoration: none;
         }
         .data ul{
         list-style-type: none;
         }
         .profile{
         height: 40px;
         width: 40px;
         float: left;
         margin: 0px 13px;
         }
         .details{
         font-size: 13px;
         }
         li.title {
         border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
         overflow: hidden;
         margin-bottom: 5px;
         padding: 5px 0;
         }
         .active{
         background:#ececec;
         }
         p{
         margin:0px;
         padding: 0px;
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul class="organogram">
            <li id='dept-1' class='team'>
               <div class='data'>
                  <ul>
                     <li class='title' onclick='thisNode(this)'>
                        <a href='#'>
                           <img src='img/1.jpg' class='profile' >
                           <div class='details'>
                              <p>Tusher1</p>
                              <p>Designation</p>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class='title' onclick='thisNode(this)'>
                        <a href='#'>
                           <img src='img/1.jpg' class='profile' >
                           <div class='details'>
                              <p>Tusher2</p>
                              <p>Designation</p>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class='title' onclick='thisNode(this)'>
                        <a href='#'>
                           <img src='img/1.jpg' class='profile' >
                           <div class='details'>
                              <p>Tusher3</p>
                              <p>Designation</p>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
```